# Symlink - Change specific files

Tags: linux, symlink

I've sym-linked a directory, and now I want to change a specific file in the linked directory, without changing it in the target directory. I don't want to copy the whole directory.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, there is only 1 directory.  You need to unlink the folder and link just the files or subfolders apart from the one that needs to be different.

Answer (score 0):

James is right, you can't change them because it's the same directory.

Assuming you have no subdirectories it's pretty easy to link everything individually

```
/path/to/dir2$ find /path/to/dir1 -maxdepth 1 -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 ln -s
```